# How can I perform this code in C and C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, string, while-loop

I am new to C and C++, I want this code, which goes like this in python:

```
num = ""
while current_char.isdigit():
    num += current_char
```

I want this code to be executed in C, and C++, I know I can check if a char is digit or not using the inbuilt function called isdigit(), but I don't know how to perform this code, any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, and the answer will be different for each one. In C++ `std::string` has an overload of [operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), #2 on that list, that accepts a `char` on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be something like this

```
std::string num = "";
while isdigit(current_char){
    num += current_char;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isdigit()` function, whose prototype is defined in the `<ctype.h>` file, returns a value other than `0` if a `char` value is digital.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    char current_char[] = {'1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c'};

    /* Scan all elements of character array */
    for(int i = 0 ; current_char[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    {
        /* If the character is a number, isdigit() returns a value other than 0. */
        if(isdigit(current_char[i]))
        {
            printf("%c\t", current_char[i]);

            /* Convert char value to int value and sum the result */
            number += current_char[i] - '0';
        }
    }

    printf("\nTotal: %d", number);

    return 0;
}
```

This program produces the following output:

```
1   2   3
Total: 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats how you check is digit in c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main() {
   char first = 'q';
   char second = '7';
   if(isdigit(first)) {
       printf("The character is a digit\n");
   }
   else {
       printf("The character is not a digit\n");
   } 
   if(isdigit(second)) {
       printf("The character is a digit\n");
   }
   else {
       printf("The character is not a digit");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing specific to C++ about this. This is C code. It may compile with a C++ compiler, but that does not make it C++.